# can you only use spells from one spell school?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, house-rules, druid

In 5e if a *Druid doesn't specify* a specialization do they still have to pick one, and can they only have spells from that one spell school??

okay,my DM was confused about the specification and told me to ask the internet cause he thought my character (a druid) could only pick one school and only use spells from that school. I did pick the moon circle and both of us were very confused if i could only use spells from one school or not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a specialization. Druid subclasses are called "circles"  and are unrelated to the schools of magic.

Comment: Hi Luna, and welcome to the site! Kindly take the [tour]. Am I right in believing that you mean the Circles of the Land: Arctic, Coast, Desert etc?

Comment: Actually, I think the question is clear.  "Can they only have spells from one spell school?"  As in the schools of magic, adjuration conjuration illusion necromancy.  Because all spells have a school.

Comment: @J.A.Streich The literal reading is clear, but I highly doubt that's the actual question that is meant here.

Comment: @J.A.Streich The Circle of the Land does have spell lists.

Comment: So, Luna, the reason the question is on hold is because there are two seperate things in the game you could be asking.  The first is, "Do I only get to chose one circle (like Circle of the Moon)? And When I do that does that limit my spells?" Or you could be asking, "Do I have to choose a school of magic (like conjugation), and am I limited to spell of that school?"  Both are easily answered questions, but the mods won't reopen until it is clear what you asking.

Comment: @J.A.Streich "...choose a school of magic (like **conjugation**) ..." Who knew languages were so complicated???

Comment: Well, verbs really are magic.

Answer (score 4):

A 2rd level druid *must* choose a Circle. It's not optional.

> At 2nd level, you choose to identify with a circle of druids.

(Note that it doesn't say “*may* choose” — it says you *do*. It's stating a fact about druids at 2nd level, not presenting an option.)

Circle spells are directly provided by a Druid's chosen Circle, so no, Circle spells from Circles that the Druid is not part of are not available. So even if avoiding choosing a Circle *was* possible, the result would only be not being party of *any* Circle, and therefore having no access to spells granted by Circles.

---

A note on terminology: Druids choose a **Circle**, not a **specialization** or **school**. The related spells are **Circle spells**, not **school spells**. Specializations and schools are terms used for the Wizard class, and work differently because the Wizard class has different rules.

Comment: Technically only a single druid circle (land) has circle specific spells. All druids gain access to the druid spell list, regardless of circle.

Comment: And spells have schools regardless of class.  Druids get spells of all the spell schools.

Comment: @SirCinnamon You're right; that part was written off the top of my head and I forgot that only Land Circle druids have different Circle spells. It's possible the question is asking about Land Circle spells specifically and “specialisation” is about which land the Druid is from. Let's see if the question gets clarified.

Comment: @J.A.Streich Yep. Asking about schools + specialisation specifically only makes sense for the Wizard though. We'll see what the question clarification turns up, if anything.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah I think the question needs further clarification as "specialization" could mean a number of things and "spell schools" are not applicable to druids to my knowledge

Comment: Note that the base spell list for Druids is found in the PHB, but there are supplemental lists that can be found on the ToEE companion and XGtE, if those sources are allowed at your table.